# MongoDB TTL Index is removing documents but usage is not updated

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, mongodb-compass

I have built TTL index on Timestamp property , a very straight forward index. I have created the index in my mongo context constructor using MongoDb .Net Driver V 2.7.2.
 It is removing documents as expected from a given collection but "Usage" is not updated on MongoDBCompass Community as well as when I check it via Mongo terminal.

```
<code>
Here is the out put running $indexStat:

MongoDB Enterprise > db.testCollection.aggregate( [ { $indexStats: { } } ] ).pretty()
{
        "name" : "_id_",
        "key" : {
                "_id" : 1
        },
        "host" : "****:27017",
        "accesses" : {
                "ops" : NumberLong(15),
                "since" : ISODate("2018-12-20T22:52:01.132Z")
        }
}
{
        "name" : "****TTLIndex",
        "key" : {
                "Timestamp" : -1
        },
        "host" : "****:27017",
        "accesses" : {
                "**ops" : NumberLong(0),**  <----- This is zero
                "since" : ISODate("2018-12-20T22:52:01.132Z")
        }
}
</code>
```

[image]

What might be causing the usage not to update? the other TTL indexes on other collection are working fine ?

**Edit**
I was expecting to see something like this 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `accesses` value in $indexStats is only incremented for index access driven by user requests. This does not include background TTL deletion:

> The statistics reported by the accesses field only includes index
>   access driven by user requests. It does not include internal
>   operations like deletion via TTL Indexes or chunk split and migration
>   operations.

(https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/indexStats/)

Comment: ahh, I have missed that. Thanks for pointing me to that. But what is confusing me is the Usage part in MongoDb Compass increments on other collections and they are all TTL indexes run in background :/  I added screen shot to my question to show what I was expecting.

Comment: A TTL index can still be used like a normal index, so I'm guessing that there were a few queries that used these indexes for either filtering or sorting, which would have then incremented the index to show it being used. The TTL deletion is done via a background thread (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-ttl/#delete-operations).

Comment: Thanks for clarification!